# How to show Interstitial Ad in SKScene? - SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, sprite-kit

I want to show an Interstitial Ad in the GameOverScene which is a SKScene that is shown through the main ViewController. With the code shown below the ad prints (“Ad Wasn’t Ready”) how do I fix this to work properly in the Game Over SKScene?

```
import GoogleMobileAds
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import SwiftUI

class GameOverScene: SKScene {

    var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")

        let request = GADRequest()
        interstitial.load(request)

        if interstitial.isReady {
            interstitial.present(GameViewController())
        } else {
            print("Ad wasn't ready")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably because you're not giving the ad time to load. The ad request is an `async` request, so when you call `interstitial.load(request)` you have to wait for the ad request to complete and the interstitial ad to be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You're presenting ad before the load is completed. You need to show in delegate callback once the Ad is loaded successfully.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
}

func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
  var interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
  interstitial.delegate = self
  interstitial.load(GADRequest())
  return interstitial
}

func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
  interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
}
```

Show the ad in load success callback.

/// Tells the delegate an ad request succeeded.

```
func interstitialDidReceiveAd(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
    print("interstitialDidReceiveAd")
    if ad.isReady {
        ad.present(fromRootViewController:self)
    } else {
        print("Ad wasn't ready")
    }
}
```

You can find more details here, https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial